# Inline edit update and delete listview through gridview in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I need to implement gridview inline edit, update and delete operations through listview in WPF from db similar to normal windows datagridview. Can we achieve same kind of operation through a listview in wpf implementing MVVM also at the same time. If yes, please let me know with a sample example..else please help me with any other option..

Comment: Please use WPF DataGrid for this. ListView inline edit has to be explicitly templated. DataGrid inherently provides all that.

Comment: thank you..but then I did not find a DataGrid control by default in WPF ..can you please help me the way out to reslove it..

Comment: If you are using .Net 4.0 then it is supported as part of WPF framework .... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx. But If you are using older versions of .Net then refer the WPF Toolkit assemblies (they are freely distributed over internet)... http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

Comment: sorry.. I didn't get the control even after using the given xlmns, namespaces also..am using Visual studio 2010 sp1

Comment: What are you using? .Net 4.0? Or the toolkit? .... Knowing you are using Visual Studio 2010 does not tell me if your .net version is 4.0 or less.